# What is the best way to place horizontal and vertical photos in the same size rectangles?

Tags: html, css, image, background

I am creating an online bazaar where people will upload portrait and landscape photos.
I'm doing a page with product previews that will always have a photo of the product and a title. There will be several products on one page.I would like to ask what is the best practice to style the images so that they have the same size and style? Should I use background or img?

I would like it to look similar to the picture.

Thanks for help[image]

Comment: What do you want to happen on different viewport dimensions? And have you investigated object-fit: cover which will allow you to have different aspect ratioed images within the same size cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The images are relevant to the content so the best practice is to use an `img` tag.** This is the semantically correct way.

I had this problem myself in the past. Here is the solution I came up with, that works for vertical and horizontal images in your grid:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.img-container {
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

img {
    max-width: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/400" alt="Dog 1">
    </div>
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1025/400/300" alt="Dog 2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Would this solution work for your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Best approach to achieve this is by using Grid layout with grid layout you can specify the width and height of one call and the other cells will inherit it also. And the responsiveness is also achieved this method.
You can refer to this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid)
And This [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)  also

Comment: Thanks for answer! Yeah, I created a grid layout with 5 columns.But I would like to now how to best fit the image in this column. So that the images are all the same size, not distorted, and so that the product can be clearly seen on them.I need it to work well even if someone uploads a portrait or landscape image for example.

Comment: You can process the image while uploading or set rules for uploading the image. And you can also fix the width and height perimeters of image so that all images look same

Answer (score 0):

Best approach to achieve this is by using Grid with grid you can specify the width and height of one call and the other cells will inherit it also. And the responsiveness is also achieved this method.